# Could not load file or assembly 'Kusto.Cloud.Platform, version = 1.0.0.0' when it is referenced from Azure Func v1

Tags: dependencies, nuget-package, azure-data-explorer, target-framework

I am referencing a .NetFramework v4.6 library project which has **Azure.kusto.Data package version 4.0.3** with dependency 'Kusto.Cloud.Platform', Version 1.0.0.0' when this library is referenced by Azure Funcion V1, It is throwing the below innerException

"*Could not load file or assembly 'Kusto.Cloud.Platform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829a00acde12d551' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Kusto.Cloud.Platform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829a00acde12d551"} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}*"

As the library Azure.Kusto.Data Package has been referenced by some other services upgrading is not an options. I have clear the solutions, remove the solution package and clear the nuget cache and none of them helped.

Can you help why the Azure func v1 is not able to locate the "Kusto.Cloud.Platform, Version=1.0.0.0" which I can verify the existince of package in the libary bin folders?

Comment: Please use the latest version of the package.

Comment: Thank you  @VladikBranevich for the suggestion,  We have external service dependency with this version of the package (Azure.Kusto.Data 4.0.3) because upgrading will bring some other dependency issue, we are not looking upgrading for now.

Comment: I have unlisted this version (it wasn't unlisted by accident), as it references a private build of another library. I strongly recommend you to move to a more advanced version. Also please note that since 4.0.3 multiple issues have been fixed and perf issues addressed.